Emulator working but not displaying on windows?
I am trying to learn flutter but when I start to run it everything works but the emulation wont pop on windows it open and it displays on the taskbar but when i try to open it it won't open as you can see there is the app on the task bar but i cant open it screen shoot of the problem
i have tried wiping the data of the emulator and also cold booting

first time emulator load can take some time,

If you hove your mouse over the icon it show the mini preview image?

Its not about time it wont open

Try Deleting the device from android studio and create a new one
